# Create simple JSON structure using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'd just like to create the Jackson mapping equivalent of the below :

```
{\"isDone\": true}
```

I think I need to create a class like this :

```
public class Status {

    private boolean isDone;

    public boolean isDone{
        return this.isDone;
    }

    public void setDone(boolean isDone){
        this.isDone = isDone;
    }
}
```

But how do I instatiate it and then write the JSON to a string ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A problem with your example and Jackson is the default choices of JSON property names: Jackson will see `isDone` and `setDone` and choose `done` as the JSON property name. You can override this default choice using the `JsonProperty` annotation:

```
public class Status
{
    private boolean isDone;

    @JsonProperty("isDone")
    public boolean isDone()
    {
        return this.isDone;
    }

    @JsonProperty("isDone")
    public void setDone(boolean isDone)
    {
        this.isDone = isDone;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Status instance = new Status();
String jsonString = null;

instance.setDone(true);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(instance);
```

Now `jsonString` contains `{ "isDone" : true }`. Note that you can also write the string to an `OutputStream` using [ObjectMapper.writeValue(OutputStream, Object)](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.Object%29), or to a `Writer` using [ObjectMapper.writeValue(Writer, Object)](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html#writeValue%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.Object%29).

In this case you really only need the `JsonProperty` annotation on either of your accessors, but not both. Just annotating `isDone` will get you the JSON property name that you want.

An alternative to using the `JsonProperty` annotation is to rename your accessors `setIsDone/getIsDone`. Then the annotations are unnecessary.

See the quick and dirty Jackson tutorial: [Jackson in 5 minutes](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes). Understanding of the specific properties came from looking through the docs for Jackson annotations.

Comment: thanks, can you point me in the direction where this is explained ? or is it scattered among the docs?

Answer (score 2):

Right. The code needed:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Status()));
```